# In a SQL(Oracle) time query I get the month instead of the minutes

Tags: sql, oracle

In our internal software, I'm querying the time of a task.
Because our software is based in Europe, the time is european time but I need the US one so I use the "at time zone to convert it.
To show you the problem, I've queried it twice. Onence before conversion and once after.
So the issue is that the `"MM"` of `"HH:MM"` is giving me the month instead of the minutes.
So I get `12:10(10 is the month)` and I should have got `12:12` (it was `17:12` european time).
I put a screen capture of the results

[Before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tb18.png)

```
select 
t.actual_start_dttm before_conversion,
to_char(cast(t.actual_start_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'HH:MM') after_conversion
from task t
where task_id = '695421'
```

Comment: i have added answer..let me know if it works or else i can suggest another way of conversion

Comment: perfect. Thank you

Comment: you have posted bymistake an incorrect answer...instead please marked the question as acceptance if its solved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change the query and use 'MI' instead of 'MM'

```
select 
t.actual_start_dttm before_conversion,
to_char(cast(t.actual_start_dttm as timestamp) at time zone 'US/Eastern', 'HH:MI') after_conversion
from task t
where task_id = '695421'
```

For more information you can refer below link :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6381/index-en.html

Comment: Oh thank you it works, I don't understand. Most of the websites I was looking said MM.

Answer (score 0):

Minutes has Format `MI` not `MM`...

Comment: Oh thank you it works, I don't understand. Most of the websites I was looking said MM.

Comment: @Alain: don't look at random websites, [read the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96)

Comment: Perhaps you where on a website for another programming language `Java` or something. Make sure you get the correct manuel as @a_horse_with_no_name already stated.